# Can Ion Auth Login User Without Password for Integration with Hybrid Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, hybridauth, ion-auth

Is the above possible and does it pose a security threat?

I'm using HybridIgniter adaptation of HybridAuth to authenticate an user and log them in. If the user has authenticated previously I use that information to get the email and user id. I need to log users in on Ion Auth with Codeigniter by either passing an encrypted password (from the db) or using no password at all.

Thanks.

-Patrick

Answer (score 0):

It can be a huge security risk and I advise you not to do it.

If in any case you want to go ahead here is a possible solution

Create another field like password2, and store an encrypted password you know of. Switch data between the fields 'password' and 'password2', log them in and switch again.

P.S. If you are trying to do it after email confirmation, its better to just ask the user to log in.